# Plot a chart with specific columns in Python through a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make a chart from a dataframe in Pandas, but I can't configure `matplotlib.pyplot` the way I need it.

```
    industry                nps     year
11  Transportation          50.84   2020
6   Professional Services   52.59   2020
3   Life Sciences           43.15   2020
26  Transportation          39.28   2019
21  Professional Services   43.52   2019
18  Life Sciences           40.19   2019
41  Transportation          37.66   2018
36  Professional Services   27.61   2018
33  Life Sciences           34.11   2018
56  Transportation          17.60   2017
51  Professional Services   17.33   2017
48  Life Sciences           -3.33   2017
```

The chart output I need is in this way as in the image.
[image]

How can I configure matplotlib.pyplot correctly for this output?
Thanks

Comment: Use [seaborn's barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='industry', y='nps', hue='year',
                 palette=['#4472C4', '#FFFF00', '#92D050', '#7030A0'],
                 edgecolor='k',
                )
sns.move_legend(ax, "upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
```

output:

[image: seaborn barplot]